# How can I fit <img> to the entire browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Question:
If you are using

```
<img>
```

in html, how would you style that element in css to make a large image fit the browser window with no white space?

Situation:
I am working on a project that has me a bit stumped. The idea is a slideshow for the webpage background. In the .html file I have created the slideshow with javascript. The single image element is what javascript uses to shuffle through the five images that will be there. (I am just using one for now to get sizing right.)

My slideshow works but my image is huge and does not perfectly fit the browser window. :( This tells me that my other images will have the same problem when I plug them into the javascript array. (they are all quite large)

I am thinking that I may have to use a div container but I am not sure how. I'm the new guy.

Here is my javascript with  for the slidesow:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Raptor sand.jpg"
        ];
        </script>    

        <div class="container">
            <img src="Africa Twin Mountainside.jpg" id="slide" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <script>
        var step = 0;
        function slideit(){
        document.getElementById('slide').src = images[step];
        step++;
        if(step>=images.length)
        step=0;
        setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);                
        }
        slideit(); 
        </script>
```

and here is my css

```
.container{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;    
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this has anything to do with scripting, it's all about HTML and styling.

Comment: use `background-size` in css follow link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: It doesnt but I cannot use Mandar Sant's idea because in this scripting situation I have to use the image element. I just gave the scenario in case anyone wanted to know why I am not just using background-image.

Comment: The exact question is at the top of the post

Comment: Please don't pass function calls to `setTimeout` as strings.  This angers the internet Gods.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1200/800'); background-size: cover; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left:0"></div>
```

(inline styles because I'm being lazy.  Obviously these should live in a stylesheet).

sub out url for correct image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this

```html
<img src="picture.jpg" alt="My picture" id="target">
 <script src="./jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $( "#target" ).height( $( window ).height() );
          $( "#target" ).width( $( window ).width() );
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Why use jQuery for a thing that can be done via vanilla javascript? Besides, the OP hasn't even tagged the question with jQuery.

Comment: I'm just posting one way to do the job.